# RSpec + Capybara + Selenium Webdriver: Test that modal button triggers jquery that checks a box is not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara

This is working in development when tested by hand. But Capybara isn't catching it.

Working JS:

```js
$(document).on("click", "#modal_accept_waiver", function() {
  $("#registration_accept_waiver").prop("checked", true);
  $("#waiverModal").modal('hide');
});
```

HTML/ERB:

```html
<%= simple_form_for [@event, @registration] do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  ...form fields...
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :user do |o| %>
    ...more form fields...
    <div>
      <h4>
        <%= f.check_box :accept_waiver, required: true %>
          <strong>Accept the 
            <a id="waiver_click" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#waiverModal" href="#">
              Waiver and Release
            </a>
          </strong>
      </h4>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit 'Register', class: 'btn yellow use-load-screen' %>
<% end %>
```

Capybara test:

```rb
it 'has a modal for the waiver, which checks the box', js: true do
  expect(page).to have_unchecked_field('registration_accept_waiver') # passes

  click_on 'waiver_click' # works

  within('#waiverModal') do
    expect(page).to have_content 'Waiver of Liability' # passes
    click_on 'Accept' # works
  end

  expect(page).to have_content event.title # just to force Capybara to wait for the JS to complete
  expect(page).to have_checked_field('registration_accept_waiver') # fails
end
```

Output:

```rb
Register for Event
  when anon user
Capybara starting Puma...
* Version 4.3.1 , codename: Mysterious Traveller
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 4
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:61204
    has a modal for the waiver, which checks the box (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) Register for Event when anon user has a modal for the waiver, which checks the box
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_checked_field('registration_accept_waiver')
       expected to find visible field "registration_accept_waiver" that is not disabled that is checked but there were no matches. Also found "", which matched the selector but not all filters. Expected checked true but it wasn't

     [Screenshot]: tmp/screenshots/failures_r_spec_example_groups_register_for_event_when_anon_user_has_a_modal_for_the_waiver__which_checks_the_box_288.png

     ...stuff...

Finished in 6.73 seconds (files took 5.88 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure
```

Looking at the screenshot confirms the checkbox is not checked. So does using `save_and_open_page`.

But, when I force the test to fail in different places, I can see the modal open and close as expected in screenshots. This tells me some of the JS is working as expected.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Setup:

- RSpec
- Rspec-retry
- Capybara
- Selenium webdriver

rails_helper.rb:

```rb
config.before(:each, type: :system, js: true) do
  driven_by :selenium_chrome_headless
  Capybara.page.driver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(1920, 2024)
end
```

Comment: You could try setting the attribute to `checked="checked"` instead of just true.

Comment: @max, same result. `$("#registration_accept_waiver").prop("checked", "checked");` works when I test it myself. But Capybara fails to find it.

Comment: Also tried plain old javascript instead of JQuery, but still no luck.

Comment: If the screenshot isn't showing the checkbox checked then it's not that Capybara isn't catching it, it's that the box isn't being checked.  I would guess you have an error in one of your JS files that is causing the combined JS asset to be illegal and therefore not attaching the desired behavior.  This doesn't happen in dev mode because JS assets are served individually, rather than concatenated as they are in test and production, there so an error in one file doesn't prevent the other file from working properly.  Check your console log for any JS errors and fix them.